error trying to import module pinned in import map
I have a rails 7 app and I'm trying to add hotwire functionality. I am getting an error with pinning stimulus and importing it in application.js
importmap.rb
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"

application.js
import "stimulus.min.js"

application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chargemaster</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    hello
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

I get the following error loading the page:
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus.min.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. My understanding is that the importmap defines a module specifier stimulus.min.js and I can use that module specifier to refer to the imported package within my app, such as within application.js.
note: the name "stimulus.min.js" was not what I would have called it; I honestly don't remember where it came from - either a tutorial or a SO answer or some chatgpt generated code that I tried before bothering real people. To my mind it doesn't make sense to use the .min pre-suffix in the name; I have no idea whether the package I'm importing is minified, and just calling it that doesn't make it so. I'm just trying to learn how this stuff works :)
If it helps please feel free to look at the source for the entire project in github:
https://github.com/fredwillmore/climate-control

you should create a sample app with rails new so you can see how everything is configured in rails 7. it's import "@hotwired/stimulus"

ok so the suggestion from @alex was a sensible one - I just generated a new rails app and copied the implementation over to mine:
config/importmap.rb
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

And it works!

Import maps allow you to use the Javascript files packaged inside gems. This is instead of installing with yarn or Webpacker. This line is telling your application to look inside the installed gem for the minified JS file.
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"

You can run bundle info stimulus to determine where your stimulus-rails gem is installed. In my case, I use asdf, so the gem is in
~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/stimulus-rails-1.3.3/ and the file is in GEM_PATH/app/assets/javascripts/.
If your application can't find the file, it's probably not downloaded yet. This should do the trick.
bundle install

If it is, and the JS file got deleted, you can manually uninstall the gem and then reinstall it with bundler:
gem uninstall stimulus-rails
bundle install

